# How do I limit Oracle to use specific ports?

Tags: oracle, configuration, network, oracle-9i, oracle-fail-safe

I've built a new Oracle 9iR2 instance on a Windows 2003 32-bit cluster. Of course, it's version 9i for reasons out of my control.  Several application servers connect to this instance, and each opens several `DEDICATED` connections that they keep open for their work.

This instance is in a locked-down environment, so my network guys want to seal off as many ports as possible. To do that, I need to tell them precisely what ports or port ranges the instance needs open.

I've skimmed the [Listener documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96580/listener.htm), and I can see that I can change the default Listener port of 1521. However, every connection these application servers open against the database appears to get its own TCP port.

Is there any way to limit the range of ports these servers will use to connect to the database?

Comment: More or less random Googling finds this: [Configure the max limit for concurrent TCP connections](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html). Perhaps it can help.

Comment: **9i** in 2012?? Who on earth would want to do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It's part of a highly-customized third-party application. The business is unwilling to invest in properly updating the application per the vendor's recommendations.

Comment: @ypercube - Registry hacking makes me nervous, especially in a cluster where registry changes have to be replicated across all nodes.

Comment: if the listener runs on port 1521 of dbserver and you open a dedicated connection from your clientcomputer then the socket pair that constitutes that connection is from `clientcomputer:someport` to `dbserver:1521`. you really want to restrict `someport`?

Comment: @miracle173 - That's incorrect. The connection is `dbserver:someport` to `client:someport`. The initial request from the client goes to the listener on port 1521, but is then redirected to a different port to establish the connection.

Comment: then you dont use a dedicated connection but you use so called multithreaded or shared servers. there is a possibility to restrict the ports. i will post an answer

Comment: @miracle173 - Oh, you're right! The `SERVER` clause is not specified in the `TNSNAMES` file on the client servers, meaning they will default to `SHARED` connections. Is that correct?

Comment: if the server is configured for "multithreaded (share) server" then the desaukt connections is a shraed on. you must explicitely configure `SERVER=DEDICATED` in the tnsnames.ora file to override this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the listener runs on port 1521 of the database server and you open a `dedicated` connection then the socket pair that constitutes that connection is from `client:clientport` to `dbserver:1521`.

If you have connections of the type `dbserver:serverport` to `client:clientport` than you don't have a `dedicated` connection but you have a multithreaded server (or shared sever in higher version) running. You can restrict the possible number of ports used by the server by configuring the ports of the dispatcher explicitly.

> Oracle9i Net Services Administrator's Guide Release 2 (9.2) 
>   Part Number A96580-02
>
> [14 Configuring Shared Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96580/mts.htm#447168)
>
> Example: Dispatcher Address with PORT To force the exact location of
>   the dispatchers, add the PORT as follows in the init.ora file or
>   spfile:
>
> `DISPATCHERS="(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST=144.25.16.201)(PORT=5000))(DISPATCHERS=1)"`
>   `DISPATCHERS="(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST=144.25.16.201)(PORT=5001))(DISPATCHERS=1)"`

Comment: @Nick Chammas: Is there anything unclear with this answer?

Comment: Nope, thank you for posting this. Actually, more important than this answer were your comments above leading me to realize that I've been connecting to the database in `SHARED` and not `DEDICATED` mode! I haven't had a chance to look at this problem at work more thoroughly, but when I get back to it I will revisit this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to visit the Connection Manager documenatation  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/network.804/a58230/ch7.htm#439171)

I have used it to concentrate connections - we had a client that needed to access our database over a VPN. The firewall was only configured to open 1 port for all their connections. We were able to handle all their traffic over this 1 port using CMAN. Your mileage may vary though, we just used it for a handful of connections, if you are servicing dozens or hundreds of connections CMAN may run out of steam.

Your network guys should also check with the firewall vendor, there may be the ability for the firewall to open ports after the listener hands them off... So the firewall still has control over what gets opened and when after Oracle authenticates the connection. I don't know what this feature called as I am not heavy on the network side, but we had to use CMAN for some of our firewalls that did not handle this.

Comment: Thank you for specifically calling out [Connection Concentration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/network.804/a58230/ch7.htm#434447). I had taken a cursory look at CMAN, but wasn't sure how it could help. The database *will* service well over 100 persistent connections. Do you think managing them all will be too much for CMAN? I'll check with my network guys on what our firewall can do.

Comment: All I can really say is "I don't know". Personally I wouldn't expect 1 port to take the place of dozens or hundreds of ports... But I have been working with Oracle for 10+ years and I am jaded :) Our client had less than a dozen concurrent connections and used it for ad-hoc queries so the connections were mostly idle. If you are funneling hundreds of OLTP type connections through it... it may handle it just fine I would say test it before you rely on it for production so no surprises.